# What does "high to take care" mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

I need to translate an item from a questionnaire: “My parents were too drunk or high to take care of the family.”, but I don't understand the part "... or high to take care ...". How to understand the word *high* in this phrase?

---

P.S. I assumed it is a slang, as is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substance_intoxication), but I was not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Too drunk or high' is a shortening of 'too drunk or too high'. The parents could not take care of the family because they were either too drunk or too high. 'High' here means 'intoxicated by drugs'.